# Compare input in google forms and google sheets value by appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Ok, I have a google form with some thing to input, say a employee code. When someone enters a code, I need to compare this code with a code I have in google sheets. Is it possible (with or without using apps-script.)? If its possible, I need to show the next form accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to show the next form accordingly"? Also, please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I submitted '10010001' code in forms. Now i need to tally it to google sheets. If the codes match, then in the next form I need to display employee list that matches the 1st five characters of this code as answers.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the only item in your google form then this code will return true if it matches any item in column 1 of Sheet named "ListOfCodes"

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('ListOfCodes')
  const listofcodes=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow()).getValues().map(function(r){return r[0];})
  if(listofcodes.indexOf(e.values[1])!=-1) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

I added this code to test it and it's working fine.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('ListOfCodes')
  const listofcodes=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow()).getValues().map(function(r){return r[0];})
  var idx=listofcodes.indexOf(e.values[1]);
  if(idx!=-1) {
    Logger.log(idx)
    return true;
  }
}
```

How are you running it?

Comment: I added this code on my forms script and so it did not find spreadsheet i think.

Comment: You asked about doing a comparison with entered data.  You said nothing about finding a spreadsheet and you have posted no code.  Please post your code and provide a better explanation.

Comment: @Bista You should add it to sheets script NOT in forms.